# Interactive Detection Service in Windows 8 beta

Tags: windows, service, interactive

I have installed Windows 8 consumer preview. When trying to start the "Interactive Detection Service" from Service Console Manager, I am running getting the following problem.

"The Interactive Services Detection service terminated with the following error: 
Incorrect function."

I am running as the Administrator logged in remotely from RDP. How ever I am able to start/stop other services.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft have changed the default behaviour of this in Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012. To allow interactive services, you need to find the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows and change NoInteractiveServices from 1 to 0.